# unable to multiply matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication

Good day!

I am trying to multiply two matrices those are:

z = [64 x 1] ; with complex attribute.

top = [32 x 64]

both of the matrices class are double but when I tried to run the program I got an error at the last line

> Matrix dimensions must agree.

here is the code:

```
clear all; clc;
load('eeg.mat'); 

load('top.mat');

N = 64;
M = 32;


Psi = dftmtx(N);
z = Psi * VarName1;
y = z * top;
```

the output that I want is [32 x 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have the product `y = z * top` where `size(z) == [64, 1]` and `size(top) == [32, 64]`. The sizes of these two matrices are incompatible to be multiplied in this order, as the "inner" dimensions must agree, but in your case  `1 ~= 32` (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Definition). What you probably want is

```
y = top * z
```

Comment: how clumsy I am! thank you so much for answering my question.